# Add Headers and Footers to Word Document with Power Shell

Tags: powershell, scripting, ms-word

I am looking for a way to insert headers and footers into a Microsoft Word document that was generated from within Power Shell.  Is there a way to do this?  If so, what is an example of some code needed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Create a new Word application COM object
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
# Make the Word application visible
$Word.Visible = $true;
# Add a new document to the application
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
# Get the first Section of the Document object
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
# Get the header from the Section object
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
# Get the footer from the Section object
$Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1);

# Set the text for the header and footer
$Header.Range.Text = "Hey, I'm the header!";
$Footer.Range.Text = "Hey, I'm the footer!";

# Create a Table of Contents (ToC)
$Toc = $Doc.TablesOfContents.Add($Section.Range);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, the way that you have the Sections listed, would that be able to be used for generating a table of contents within the same type of Power Shell generated Word document?

Comment: $Toc = $Doc.TablesOfContents.Add($Section.Range);

Comment: Awesome information.  If there a reference that I can look some more of this up with?  Also, how would I go about adding bold to the text both in a paragraph and within the header?  What about setting the horizontal placement of text, such as center, left, or right?

Comment: I use Google to find out this type of stuff. If you can't find a PowerShell example, search for a C# example and translate it into PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Document = "c:\temp\tralala.doc" # Must exist

$Word = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $true
$ExistingDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($document)
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$ExistingDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 1
$Selection.TypeText("Here is my automated header")
$ExistingDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 4
$Selection.TypeText("Here is my automated footer")
$ExistingDoc.Save()
$Word.Quit()
```

For having a list of possible values for SeekView, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211923%28v=office.11%29.aspx). WdSeekView section.