# Automate replacements of a ms-word document's footer and very first paragraph for 200 files

Tags: replace, ms-word, automation

We have to automatically replace the footers and the first paragraph of about 200 documents, both the footer and the first paragraph contain an image that must also be replaced.  The new footer and the new paragraph are identical for all documents. The existing footer contain the page number, so that the new footer should also contain the page number.

Is writing an automation faster than doing this one by one?

I imagine a process that opens each document that is located in a specific folder, replaces the footer and the documents' first paragraph, after that the document is saved (under the same name or a different name) and closed.

Any ideas? Macros? VBA? Any approximate example would be a great help!

Comment: Automating that kind of thing with PowerShell should be relatively easy. See here for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727919/add-headers-and-footers-to-word-document-with-power-shell

Comment: Thanks David! In the meantime we did it "manually" in one day. Maybe next time we will use PowerShell.